# ExtJS 5.1: Change the store of combobox on form 'boxready' event

Tags: events, extjs, combobox

I'm having a problem with performing any action on combobox's store on the form's `boxready` event or at any other event that occurs before the dialog is fully rendered (combobox's `afterrender`, etc.).

E.g. something like `this.getCombobox().getStore().removeAll()` works perfectly on any event firing up on the form, except the ones that happen initially during dialog/elements loading...

Answer (score 1):

> problem with performing any action on combobox's store on the form's
>   boxready event or at any other event that occurs before the dialog is
>   fully rendered (combobox's afterrender, etc.)

[No problems at all](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/prm):

```
Ext.widget({
    xtype: 'form',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'combo',
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
                data : [
                    {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
                    {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
                    {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
                ]
            }),
            fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'abbr',
            listeners: {
                'afterrender': function() {
                    console.log("combo's afterrender");
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        'boxready': function() {
            console.log("form's boxready");
            this.down('combo').getStore().setData([
                    {"abbr":"ME", "name":"Middle Earth"}
                ]);
        },
        'afterrender': function() {
            console.log("form's afterrender");
        }        
    }
});
```

By the way, as you can see in the fiddle, `boxready` happens after `afterrender`, not before.